# Openshift copy image to another image repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, openshift, amazon-ecr

I have an openshift deployment with buildConfig as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: BuildConfig
metadata:
  name: '#OKD_COMPONENT_NAME#'
spec:
  output:
    to:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: '#OKD_COMPONENT_NAME#:latest'
  runPolicy: SerialLatestOnly
  source:
    git:
      uri: '#CI_REPOSITORY_URL#'
      ref: '#CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME#'
    type: Git
    contextDir: #OKD_COMPONENT_NAME#
  strategy:
    dockerStrategy:
      buildArgs:
        - name: "CA_HOSTS_LIST"
          value: "get-ca-cert.apps.test.fr:443 get-ca-cert.apps.test.fr:443  get-ca-cert.apps.test.fr:443"
    type: Docker
  triggers:
  - type: ConfigChange
  - imageChange: {}
    type: ImageChange
```

At the end of the build openshift build the image and push it to its internal registry.

The issue is that I want to copy that image build and pushed to openshift internal registry to AWS ECR. The openshift pods has to be created with images in the openshift internal registry but I just want to also have a copy of that image pushed to internal registry automatically in AWS ECR also.

I there a way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this, but `oc image mirror` command may fit for your use case, refer [Transferring Images](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/managing_images.html#managing-images-mirror-registry-images)
 for more details. This command can copy an image in the registry to the multiple registries. For example, it shows how to copy the internal image "image:latest" to `docker.io` and `quay.io`.

```
oc image mirror docker-registry.default.svc.cluster.local/project/image:latest \
   docker.io/project/image:stg \
   quay.io/project/image:prod
```

For the automation, you may do this through the script which implements above copy tasks using [Configuring Post Commit Build Hooks](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/builds/build_hooks.html#configuring-post-commit-build-hooks) trigger, or you may need to more complicated build process like [Jenkins Pipeline](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/builds/build_strategies.html#pipeline-strategy-options) for this.